# Find and sort 2d array elements like radar

Tags: sorting

I don't know relevant keywords about this algorithm.
I can show you visually
[image: Sort elements like circular pattern]

[image: Second image is result]

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: ("scan|sweep line" or "line|plane scan|scanning|sweep|sweeping" and "polar coordinates"?) Are you looking for terminology or algorithm? Tag accordingly!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order/6989383#6989383

Comment: This reminds me of parts of the [Jarvis March algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) or [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) for convex hull calculation. Maybe these articles will give you some additional wording clues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each of your points in the field, calculate the red angle:
    [image]

Then sort all the (point, angle)-tuples by the angle.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to sort points by angle in Swift:

```
let radarSortedPoints: [CGPoint] = points.sorted { pointA, pointB -> Bool in
    atan2(pointA.y, pointA.x) < atan2(pointB.y, pointB.x)
}
```

Comment: Just a note, the use of atan2 is not necessary, see https://github.com/Laakeri/contestlib/blob/master/src/geometry/anglesort.cpp for an implementation that is exact for integers.

Comment: @Laakeri Isyourspacekeybroken? lol why would you type def something as clear as `complex<long long>` to something as arbitrary and cryptic as `co`?